# str.join with my types

Tags: python, string, inheritance, overriding

Is there opportunity to join my types using:

```
str.join()
```

I have my class:

```
class Slice(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.__start = start
        self.__end = end

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}:{1}'.format(self.__start, self.__end)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "'{}'".format(str(self))
```

What should i override to perform this kind of code:

```
','.join(Slice(1, 2), Slice(3, 4))
```

And get a result like this:

```
'1:2,3:4'
```

Comment: That's `str.join()`, not `string.join()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing.

```
','.join(str(x) for x in (Slice(1, 2), Slice(3, 4)))
```

Comment: thanx, the answer is obvious, how couldn't i guess myself (=

Comment: I feel like I just woke up. Thank you. So this is why Guido wanted to get rid of `map` and friends...

Answer (score 0):

I always just do this:

```
','.join(map(str, (Slice(1, 2), Slice(3, 4)))
```

But you could also create a utility function:

```
def strseq(*args):
    for arg in args:
        yield str(arg)
','.join(strseq(Slice(1, 2), Slice(3, 4)))
```

I think this is intentional and generally a good thing: Python is strictly typed and that will shake out some silly bugs at run-time. So don't try to make the `Slice` a `str`, but instead `map` to `str`.

If you *really* want to go hacky, do this:

```
class Slice(str):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.__start = start
        self.__end = end
        str.__init__('{0}:{1}'.format(self.__start, self.__end))
```

I keep getting an error "TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)" when I call `str.__init__(self, 'test')` in the constructor, which would normally be the correct way to do this, I think, so this is a good sign that you are not supposed to be subclassing `str`. But go ahead. Shoot yourself in the foot. It hurts, but in the good old-fashioned learn-something-new-a-day way :)

Comment: `str` is immutable, so even in `__init__` you can't change it. You'd want to override `__new__`. (It's still a bad idea in this case though.)

Comment: Ah, @PetrViktorin thanks, I keep forgetting about that one. Normally, I tend to stay away from arcane stuff, because if I can't remember them how can I expect the next person to? This, I learnt, after memorizing the camel book in 1999, believing all the trickery would make me one helluva hacker. Perl will either prime you for the simplest Python possible or draw you ever closer to the dark side ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it, I decided not to use any iterative function to call str(x). So here is my solution

```
x=(Slice(1, 2), Slice(3, 4))
','.join(['%s']*len(x)) % x
```